# Finding the Maximum of SinIntegral[x]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization, special-functions

I want to find the maximum value of `SinIntegral[x]` in numerical value and its value of `x` in exact value. I used

```
NMaximize[SinIntegral[x], x]
```

and it found `{1.85194, x -> 3.14159}` (which I'm assuming is the numerical). However, I am having trouble finding the minimum in as an exact value? I tried using

```
Solve[SinIntegral'[x] == 0, x]
```

since the local maximum of values of `x`  for `SinIntegral'[x]` go from positive to negative. However, Mathematica says that some solutions may not be found but ends up givng `x -> 396 π`

Comment: Try `Solve[SinIntegral'[x] == 0, x, Method -> Reduce]`. The `N` in `NMaximize` indicates it give numericized, not exact, results.

Comment: It gives a long result of conditional expression, but not exact value .

Comment: It gives infinitely many exact values, parametrized by an integer `C[1]`, for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/aCWMw.png

Comment: I'm assuming you know the derivative, by hand, is $(\sin x)/x$, which leads to relative max. at $x=\pi$ by elementary calculus.

Comment: Try `Maximize[{SinIntegral[x], -10 < x < 10}, x]`. Perhaps a bounded domain would be sufficient.  (I assume the problem with an infinite domain with infinitely many critical points is that *M* cannot check them all, or see which one is the greatest.)

Comment: Solve[SinIntegral'[x] == 0 && 3 < x < 4, x]

Comment: Reduce[SinIntegral'[x] == 0, x]

Answer (score 1):

Why not this?

```
max = Maximize[{SinIntegral[x], 0 <= x <= 100 π}, x]
```

> `{SinIntegral[π], {x -> π}}`

The numerical value of the maximum is given by

```
N @ max[[1]]
```

> `1.85194`

Also, since

```
Limit[SinIntegral[x], x -> ∞]
```

> `π/2`

the following plot

```
Plot[SinIntegral[x], {x, 0, 10 π},
  PlotRange -> All,
  Epilog -> 
    {Red,
     Line[{{π, 0}, {π, SinIntegral[π]}}],
     Line[{{0, π/2}, {10 π, π/2}}]}]
```

gives a visual verification (not a proof) of the result.

[image: plot]

Comment: Or a reasonably simple approximation is `SinIntegral[π] // RootApproximant[#, 2] &` which evaluates to `(59733 + Sqrt[210950061])/40097`